# How can convert the string datetime to datetime without import datetime in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I have a string, a = "4/1/2017 13:59". I need to convert it to date object.
May I know how can I convert this string datetime to datetime without import datetime in python?

Comment: How exactly do you think you could convert a string to a **`datetime`** object without importing `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
 my_time = time.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2005, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=1,
                 tm_hour=13, tm_min=33, tm_sec=0,
                 tm_wday=2, tm_yday=152, tm_isdst=-1)

timestamp = time.mktime(my_time)
# convert time object to datetime
from datetime import datetime
my_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
# convert time object to date
from datetime import date
my_date = date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

You can't convert to datetime without importing datetime